# React Router v6 add custom param into createBrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I need you help. I'm new in react router v6 so i need to add custom params in route object. But can't find any examples of it

```
 const AdminRoutes: FunctionComponent = () => {
      const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Dashboard />,
          permission: ['edit'], //custom param
        },
      ]);
    
          return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
        };
        
  export default AdminRoutes;
```

Given Error -

```
Type '{ path: string; element: JSX.Element; permission: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteObject'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'permission' does not exist in type 'RouteObject'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect these custom params to do? `createBrowserRouter` isn't going to do anything with extra properties on your `RouteObject` definitions.

Comment: I know, but i want to use this object in other places and i need to add few params, i don't want to create another config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to declare this object as a different type that extends `RouteObject` if you want to use it for other things as well.

```
type CustomRouteConfig = RouteObject & { permission: string[] }

const routeConfig: CustomRouteConfig[] = [{
  path: '/',
  element: <Dashboard />,
  permission: ['edit'], //custom param
}];

// note: you don't want to instantiate this router
// inside a functioncomponent body.
// at least stick it in a useEffect, but most likely
// this should be static.
const router = createBrowserRouter(routeConfig);

export const AdminRoutes: FunctionComponent = () => 
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
```

Comment: Thanks bro.

My fault was in this :D

const router: CustomRouteConfig[] = createBrowserRouter(routeConfig);

Comment: How would I go about doing the validation of the permissions using something like that? I'm having a hard time figuring it out with the documentation...

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a more conventional RRD way of "injecting" behavior by recommending creating a route component that takes the additional parameter as a prop and handles the logic accordingly.

Example:

```
const PermissionLayout = ({ permission }) => {
  const hasPermission = ... permission logic ...

  return hasPermission ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <PermissionLayout permission={['edit']} />
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      }
    ],
  },
  ...
]);

const AdminRoutes: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};
        
export default AdminRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import '../internationalization/i18next';
import {
  Navigate,
  IndexRouteObject,
  NonIndexRouteObject,
  createBrowserRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { LayoutAuth } from '../components';
import { SignIn } from '../containers';

type CustomRouteObjectParams = {
    category?: 'authorization' | 'administration';
    title?: string;
};

type CustomIndexRouteObject = IndexRouteObject & CustomRouteObjectParams;

type CustomNonIndexRouteObject = Omit<NonIndexRouteObject, 'children'> &
    CustomRouteObjectParams & {
        children?: (CustomIndexRouteObject | CustomNonIndexRouteObject)[];
    };

type CustomRouteConfig = CustomIndexRouteObject | CustomNonIndexRouteObject;

export const routes: CustomRouteConfig[] = [{
    path: '/auth',
    category: 'authorization',
    title: i18next.t('routes:auth'),
    element: <LayoutAuth />,
    children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Navigate to="signin" />,
        },
        {
          path: '*',
          element: <Navigate to="signin" />,
        },
        {
          path: 'signin',
          title: i18next.t('routes:signin'),
          element: <SignIn />,
        },
      ],
}]

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

export type TRoutes = typeof routes;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How would I go about doing the validation of the permissions using something like that? I'm having a hard time figuring it out with the documentation...